# Authentication problem while accessing Sharepoint Webservice

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have been using Sharepoint Services 2007 and I can able to upload any file from local system to Sharepoint server using **Copy** webservice through Asp.Net web application and I have given windows authentication.I got following error while using ***Copy.Wsdl*** in SOAPUI

Error

error -

You are not authorized to view this page

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured to accept.
Please try the following:
Contact the Web site administrator if you believe you should be able to view this directory or page.
Click the Refresh button to try again with different credentials.
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to server configuration.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI is sending a WWW-Authenitcate header which is Basic Authentication but your web service is set to only accept Integrated Authentication.

Either change the settings in SoapUI to send Integrated Authentication (may not be possible, check docs) or [change IIS to accept Basic Authentication.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324274)

Answer (score 0):

In the "Authentication and Security-related Settings", prefix the username with the relevant domain.  Even though there is separate domain field in the settings, I found that putting the domain in the username was the solution.

```
Username: domain\username
```